# How to avoid email/gtalk notifications when logged in in both, PC and Mobile?

Tags: email, notifications, google-talk

Is there a way to avoid double notification, both pc and mobile, when logged in in both? IE, my work mobile is Android based and at work we use gapps, so even if i am at my pc i get the email notification even though i'm logged in, the same with Gtalk.

Thanks!

Comment: :-) I would like an answer to the exact opposite question: how can I have the gtalk notification on EVERY machine connected to the same account? At the moment, if I'm logged on the PC, on the tablet and on the phone, when one of my contacts starts a conversation, I receive the notification ONLY on the phone. The next notifications of the same conversations arrives on the device that I use to answer...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is as designed. When an initial talk request comes in from one of your contacts, Google don't know which screen you're paying most attention to at the time. Once you reply to the message from either the PC or mobile, further notifications in that conversation should only appear on the device that you replied from.

You can totally turn off notifications on one clienmt or the other, but that doesn't sound like what you're after?

To turn off notifications totally on your mobile, open the Talk app, press <kbd>Menu</kbd> then select **Settings**, and take the tick out of "**IM Notifications**: Notify in status bar when IM arrives". The Google Talk application and web app are blocked on the PC I'm using at the moment, so can't give exact directions, but there should be a similar option to disable notifications there.

See also [How do Gmail (desktop) and Talk (Android) chats interact?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2379/how-do-gmail-desktop-and-talk-android-chats-interact)